# Нужна помощь с проектом, похожим на pix2code

Tags: python, css, нейронные-сети

Всем привет! Делаю дипломный проект, суть которого — на основе нейронной сети переводить изображение web-интерфейса в файлы с кодом HTML и css. Возникли две трудности: 1) нет идей насчет обучающей базы и 2) на каком облачном сервере лучше обучать сетку? Первую проблему можно решить в лоб, взяв обучающую базу из оригинального проекта: https://github.com/tonybeltramelli/pix2code , но мне нужна генерация css-файлов, а в том обучающем материале — только bootstrap. Буду рад вашей помощи.

Comment: Непростая это задача, вы до этого вообще нейросетями занимались, делали что-то подобное? Мне кажется такое под силу только какой-нибудь корпорации Google.

Comment: Какую именно помощь вы ожидаете? Что конкретно вам непонятно. На всякий случай напоминаю, что это сайт помощи и советов тем, кто что-то делает и у него что-то не получается. А не сайт, в котором задачу делают вместо вас. В последнем случае - вам на биржу фриланс.  Итак -  ждем КОНКРЕТНЫХ вопросов.